# MySql Stored procedure does not get executed

Tags: mysql

Here is my MySql SP:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS transformation.usp_SelectJobStatus;
CREATE PROCEDURE transformation.`usp_SelectJobStatus`(airline_code char(100), user_id int, from_date datetime, to_date datetime)
Begin
  Declare query char(255);

  Set query = 'Select * From JobMaster Where 1 = 1';

  If (Length(TRIM(airline_code)) > 0) Then
    Set query = Concat(query, " And AirlineCode = '", airline_code, "'");    
  End If; 

  If (user_id > 0) Then
    Set query := Concat(query, " And User_id = ", user_id);
  End If;

  If (from_date <> Null && to_date <> Null) Then
    Set query := Concat(query, " And SubmissionDate Between '", from_date, " And '", to_date, "'");
  End If;    

  PREPARE STMT FROM @query;
  EXECUTE STMT;
  DEALLOCATE PREPARE STMT;
End;
```

Now when I execute any of the below query it gives me an error.

```
Call usp_SelectJobStatus('ANZ', 0, null, null);
Call usp_SelectJobStatus('ANZ', 0, '2016-11-08', '2016-11-08');
```

Error:

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'NULL' at line 1

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Try modifying the statement `If (from_date <> Null && to_date <> Null) Then` to `If (from_date IS NOT Null && to_date IS NOT Null) Then`

Comment: @viki888 is null or <=> operators can only be used with null.

Comment: @Shadow Yeah. `Call usp_SelectJobStatus('ANZ', 0, null, null);` here **null** value is passed for **from_date** and **to_date** parameters

Comment: IS NOT NULL did not work. Throws the same error.

Comment: You prepared statement from "@query" which is not defined on your SP body. Maybe you don't need to write "declare query char(255)" and use "@query" for the rest. And by the way, do you have proper delimiter on your SP?

Comment: @HarshitGandhi are you using `delimiter;` in your create SP statement after `END`?

Comment: Thanks [Hermanto](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2003207/hermanto) you pointed bang on target. That's such a silly mistake from my end.